# Let Z be a random variable, What is the density function of the random variable lnZ?

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, density-function

I have the following question:

Let $Z$ be a random variable whose density function is:

$$
f(t) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{t^2} & \text{if } t \ge 1 \\
0 & \text{if } t < 1
\end{cases}$$
What is the density function of the random variable $\ln(Z)$?

The solution is as follows:

Let $Y = \ln(Z)$, then we can write $Z = e^X = g(X)$ with $g(x) = e^x$. Now we have the density function of Z:

$$h(x) = f(g(x))\frac{dg}{dx}(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-x} & \text{if } x \ge 0  \\ 0 & \text{if not}\end{cases}$$

So my question here is, why do we let this random variable $Y$ be $\ln(Z)$? It looks like we are doing something weird from the CDF to the PDF, but I am confused of what is going on here. Also, are we taking the derivative of the original density function? It looks like we have because of the $-x$ in the power of $e$.

Comment: I think they meant let $\mathbf{X}=\ln(Z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $g(x)\ge1$: $$f(g(x))=\frac{1}{(g(x))^2}=\frac{1}{(e^x)^2}=e^{-2x}$$And: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}x}=e^x$$So: $$h(x)=e^{-2x}\cdot e^x=e^{-x}$$Whenever $g(x)\ge1$, i.e. whenever $e^x\ge1,\,x\ge0$. When $g(x)<1,\,x<0$, $f(g(x))=0$.

Comment: OK, I see, but why when we are asked about $\ln(Z)$ would we express it in terms of $e^x$? Is it easier to computer and then we can just revert by taking $\ln$ again? I guess I wouldn't see that at first.

Comment: @James It's hard to understand what you're saying. If you have a way to find the density of a composite $\ln(Z)$, then you can just do that. I was just explaining how they calculated that step in the official solution

Comment: Do you know why we would take the derivative of $g(x)$ and multiply it by the composite? That is unclear to me.

Comment: Given $Y=f(X)$ for a continuously differentiable, invertible $f$, differentiate $P(X\le x)=P(Y\le f(x))$ to get the density of $X$ as $h(f(x))\cdot f'(x)$, if $h$ is the density of $Y$ @James